# What is this function called?

Tags: functions

What is this function called?
Here is a graph:

```
          _______
         /
        /
_______/
```

Sort of like:

$f(x, a, b) = 0$, if $x < a; \quad \quad \displaystyle \frac {(x - a)} {(b - a)}$ if $a < x < b; \quad \quad$ and $1$ if $ x > b$.

Closest name is Sigmoid function, but they all are smooth. Also I remember I saw similar formula for saturation, but not sure about that, googling didn't help.

**Edit:** [Ramp function is closer](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RampFunction.html):

[image]

But it is general one, while my is more specific one, used for normalization.

Comment: Note that the first function is the distribution function of the uniform distribution over $[a,b]$.

Comment: @Shai Covo It can be considered distribution function, but in other context.

Comment: You can call it pretty much whatever you want... The function-naming committee has not yet come to a final conclusion.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I call it a ramp function.  At least some others do.

Comment: More precisely, a *linear* ramp.

Comment: Ramp function (at least what I found) is first two parts of my function. Important point here is that my function range is strictly in [0; 1] and used for normalization, where ramp is general one. May be there is more specific name?

Comment: please check my edit

Comment: I have seen both being called that.  Certainly yours would qualify.

Answer (score 4):

The first two "pieces" of your graph seem to fit the "ramp" function, with $(a,0)$ replacing $(0,0)$ of the "general" example you provide for a ramp function. But the first and third "pieces" comprise what could be described as a step-function (with endpoints joined by the second "piece"/line).

But in the end, since it seems we need to define and discuss three separate "pieces" of the function, depending on the value of x with respect to the parameters $a$ and $b$, perhaps the most accurate (albeit general) description for your function is simply a *piecewise-linear* function, (consisting of a linear-ramp function which continues/plateaus at its maximum value, $y=1$  for all $x>b$?). I can't seem to find any more concise description that captures all you'd like it to capture.

Answer (score 2):

Such a function falls in the category of [Elementary special functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category%3aElementary_special_functions). You may call it a (normalized) integrated [Boxcar function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boxcar_function).

Comment: You may call it that way since it is the integral of a Boxcar function.